# Find the coset representation of $G$ by $H$. (Problem 30 on p.82 in "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, permutations

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
The following problem is Problem 30 on p.82 in this book:

> Problem 30:
> Let $G$ be $S_n$, the symmetric group of order $n$, acting as permutations on the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Let $H=\{\sigma\in G\mid n\sigma=n\}$.
>
> (a) Prove that $H$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$.
>
> (b) Find a set of elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in G$ such that $Ha_1,\dots,Ha_n$ give all the right cosets of $H$ in $G$.
>
> (c) Find the coset representation of $G$ by $H$.

**Unfortunately, in this book, the author writes the mapping $\sigma$ on the right.**

I solved Problem 30, but I am not sure my solution is ok or not.
Is my solution ok?
If not, please give me a correct solution.
About (c), what answer does the author expect?

---

The author wrote the definition of "the *coset representation* of $G$ by $H$" as follows on p.82:

> If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, let us call the mapping $\{t_g\mid g\in G\}$ defined in the discussion preceding Theorem 2.9.2 the *coset representation* of $G$ by $H$. This also realizes $G$ as a group of permutations, but not necessarily isomorphically, merely homomorphically (see Theorem 2.9.2).

The definition of $t_g$ is on p.72:

> Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Let $S$ be the set whose elements are the right cosets of $H$ in $G$. That is $S=\{Hg\mid g\in G\}$. $S$ need not be a group itself, in fact, it would be a group only if $H$ were a normal subgroup of $G$. However, we can make our group $G$ act on $S$ in the following natural way: for $g\in G$ let $t_g:S\to S$ be defined by $(Hx)t_g=Hxg$.

My solution of Problem 30 on p.82 is the following:

> (a) Let $f:S_{n-1}\to H$ be a mapping such that $i(\sigma f)=\begin{cases}
> i\sigma & (1\leq i\leq n-1)\\
> n & (i=n)
> \end{cases}$ for $\sigma\in S_{n-1}$.
> Obviously, $f$ is bijective.
> Let $\sigma,\tau\in S_{n-1}$.
> If $i\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$, then $i((\sigma\tau)f)=i(\sigma\tau)=(i\sigma)\tau=(i(\sigma f))(\tau f)=i((\sigma f)(\tau f))$ since $i\sigma\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ and $i(\sigma f)\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$.
> If $i=n$, then $i((\sigma\tau)f)=n((\sigma\tau)f)=n$ and $i((\sigma f)(\tau f))=n((\sigma f)(\tau f))=(n(\sigma f))(\tau f)=n(\tau f)=n$.
> So, $(\sigma\tau)f=(\sigma f)(\tau f)$.
> So, $f$ is an isomorphism from $S_{n-1}$ to $H$.
>
> (b) Let $a,b\in G$.
> Then, $ab^{-1}\in H$ if and only if $na=nb$.
> Let $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&\dots&n\end{pmatrix}\in G$.
> If $a_i:=\sigma^{i}$ for $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, then $Ha_1,\dots,Ha_n$ give all the right cosets of $H$ in $G$.
>
> (c) Let $\tau\in G$.
> Then, $na_i\tau=n\sigma^i\tau=i\tau=n\sigma^{i\tau}$.
> So, $t_{\tau}=\begin{pmatrix}Ha_1&Ha_2&\dots&Ha_n\\Ha_1\tau&Ha_2\tau&\dots&Ha_n\tau\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}Ha_1&Ha_2&\dots&Ha_n\\H\sigma^{1\tau}&H\sigma^{2\tau}&\dots&H\sigma^{n\tau}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: a) is not proved, in b), what are $a.b$.

Comment: @markvs I modified my answer.

Comment: In a) you still do not prove that $f$ is an isomorphism, b) is not proved, c) is not proved.

Comment: I think that your proof of (a) is misguided: surely it it trivial to check that $\sigma\mapsto\sigma|_{\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}}$ gives an isomorphism of $H$ with $S_{n-1}$. I also think that $\{e, (1n),(2n),\dots,(n-1 n)\}$ are easier coset reps to work with?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you very much for your comment. $\{e,(1n),(2n),\dots,(n-1n)\}$ is very simple and nice. I think this is the answer the author expect. Thank you!